# Send Bulk SMS by calling Twilio API using http callout

Tags: apex, trigger, api, twilio, httppost

I'm using Twilio to send SMS through salesforce.

I'm able to send the sms by calling http callout to Twilio API.

but, Now I've send bulk sms, when I inserting bulk record in salesforce.

I'm calling http callout in apex class & apex called from trigger. Currently I'm doing `http.send(req)` in `for loop`. but I think it will not work when I insert bulk record in salesforce due to governor limit.

I've refered [this post](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2009/03/16/restful-web-service-callout-using-post/). but, in this post also jeff calling http callout in for loop so this will work for bulk operation?

Is my code is correct? and  If not what is workaround to call bulk http callout.

Trigger

```
trigger UpdateContacts on Package__c(after insert) {

if (Trigger.isAfter) 
{
    list<ID> contactID = new list<ID>();
    list<string> phone = new list<string>();
    for (Package__c a : Trigger.new)
    {
       contactID.add(a.Contact__c);
    }
    for(Contact c : [Select ID, Customer_ID__c,Phone  from Contact Where ID IN :contactID])
    { 
      phone.add(c.Phone);
    }  

    SendSMS.send(phone);
}
}
```

Apex class

```
public class SendSMS
{
@future (callout=true)
public static void send(list<string> Phone )
{
    errorResponseWrapper erw;
    String smsBody='SMS body. Please don\'t reply.';

    final String  fromNumber = 'MG056832f0a17f71903b32'; 
    String account = 'AC226031e6233a3a';  
    String token   = 'token';

    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint('https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/'+account+'/Messages');
    req.setMethod('POST'); 
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(account + ':' + token);
    String authorizationHeader = 'BASIC ' +
    EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
    req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);

    for( string PhoneNo : Phone )
    {  
       if(PhoneNo != null)
       {
            req.setBody('To='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(PhoneNo,'UTF-8')+'&From='+fromNumber+'&Body='+smsBody);
            try{
                Http http = new Http();
                HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
                System.debug(res.getBody());
                if(res.getStatusCode()==201)
                  system.debug('@@@Twilio Success'+PhoneNo);
                else{
                    system.debug('@@@Twilio failed'+PhoneNo);
                     erw =(errorResponseWrapper)json.deserialize(res.getBody(),errorResponseWrapper.class);
                     system.debug('@@@Twilio error'+erw.message);
                    }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                system.debug('@@@@'+e);
            } 
        }
    }
}
public class errorResponseWrapper{
    String code;
    String message;
    String moreInfo;
    String status;    
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Twilio API doesn't support bulk message so we need to make request inside for loop. But you can try few thing. eg: In single transaction we can make 100 request so you can add these checks

```
for(Contact c : [Select ID, Customer_ID__c,Phone  from Contact Where ID IN :contactID])
    { 
      phone.add(c.Phone);
      if(phone.size() == 100) {
         SendSMS.send(phone);
          phone = new list<string>();
      }
    }  
if(phone.size() > 0)
    SendSMS.send(phone);
```

So whenever the list size reach 100 you call the method and clear the list. This will save you from getting exception.

Comment: your logic look good, but we are calling `SendSMs(phone)` from same trigger. so it is suppose to single transaction correct?. no? and salesforce allow 100 request in single transaction. So this  will work here?

Comment: @Amol as you are making request from future. So that will be separate transaction. So it work.

Comment: I've a small concern, their is limit of future annotation allowed per Apex invocation is 50. so this will affect our functionality to throw exception for bulk operation.? I'm trying to test this by writing test class for bulk operation.

Comment: @amol This can handle 5000 records at a time. If you need to process more records at a time. Then  write a batch and schedule it. That it will run hourly/daily and based on some condition it will fetch record and send message.

Comment: means I can easily insert upto 5000 record through data loader. no need to worry about this functionality, it will work correct?

Comment: @Amol yes it will unless you have some other triggers (related to this data load) which are doing similar works.